# Interpolation executed, even if ChangeDetectorRef is detached

Tags: angular, performance

I have the following situation:

- the root-component has a `<h1>` with a click-handler (the root-component uses ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default)
- below the clickable `<h1>`-Element is another component, which renders some rows. A template is specified, which defines how to render a row (and a function-call is used to get the value to render. I know, for this case a function doesn't make sense but it shows the problem)
- the component, which renders the row, is detached from change-Detection
- if I click on the `<H1>`-Element, the function is invoked again for each row in the component, although it is detached from change-detection. What is going on here?

app.component.html:

```
<h1 (click)="onClick()" style="cursor:pointer">Klick me</h1>

<app-rows [rows]="rows">
    <ng-template let-row="rowData">
        {{getName(row)}}
    </ng-template>
</app-rows>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  rows: any[];

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.rows = this.createRows(100);
  }

  getName(row:any): string {
    console.log("getName called")
    return row.name;
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log("clicked");
  }

  private createRows(count:number): any[] {
    let rows: any[] = [];

    for (let i=0; i < count; i++) {
      rows.push({
        name: "TEST " + (i+1)
      })
    }
    return rows;
  }
}
```

rows.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {'rowData': row}">
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

rows.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-rows',
  templateUrl: './rows.component.html'
})
export class RowsComponent  {

  @Input()
  rows: any[];

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  template: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeDetector.detach();
  }
}
```

The running example can be found at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prdbph)

I've uploaded a CLI-project to [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrz9hab2lbkijs0/performance-problem.zip?dl=0)

---

UPDATE: I tried to add an additional component in between to change the component hierarchy a bit. But it doesn't change the behaviour. This version can be found at [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcyf9w)

Comment: I can't run this code on the computer I am on right now but I think it may be due to the structure of the HTML. If the ChangeDetectorRef is required by a sibling, it is given the parent component's change detector, not the one provided to the host component. Can you console.log the ChangeDetectorRef and see what the view is?

Comment: I've added a link to stackblitz with the running application (see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prdbph)

Comment: After some further debugging I've found out the following:


in the angular function callViewAction(view, action) the case **ViewAction.CheckAndUpdate** is executed.


The check viewState & 12 is skipped (since the change-detector is detached).


BUT: The check viewState & 64 (CheckProjectedViews) succeeds and execProjectedViewsAction is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually a little bit complicated, the culprit for the behavior you're seeing is content projection. And it seems to be correct behavior for usual components according to the web components domain. Every projected node inside a hosting component belongs to the hosting component. So if you have the following template for the root `my-app` component:

```
<a-comp>
    <b-comp>
        <d-comp></d-comp>
    </b-comp>
</a-comp>
```

both `b-comp` and `d-comp` belong to the `my-app` component and both are considered projected. Here you can see it visually (using native shadow root):

[image]

Your case is a bit different because you're projecting a template. In Angular, when a template is projected into another component, all views created using it are considered projected as well. And they are checked when the component to which the template belongs are checked.

In the `AppComponent` template you have the following:

```
<app-rows [rows]="rows">
    <ng-template let-row="rowData">
        {{getName(row)}}
    </ng-template>
</app-rows>
```

here `ng-template` is a child of the `AppComponent` view and is projected inside the `AppRowsComponent`. This template is also bound to the `AppComponent`, but the context can be changed - you're setting it from the `RowsComponent`.

[Here is a much simpler example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-projected-template) where you can see this behavior. The projected view inside the detached component is updated when the bound parent component property is updated.

When Angular runs change detection on `AppComponent`, it checks if its children should be checked. Since `AppRowsComponent` is detached, it doesn't run change detection for it. However, the projected views created using the template bound to `AppComponent` should be checked and so there's a logic in the implementation of change detection that checks projected views:

```
// `view` here is a container for `AppRowsComponent`
case ViewAction.CheckAndUpdateProjectedViews:
    if ((viewState & 128 /* Destroyed */) === 0) {
        if (viewState & 32 /* CheckProjectedView */) {
            checkAndUpdateView(view);  <----- skipped for AppRowsComponent sicne it's not projected
        }
        else if (viewState & 64 /* CheckProjectedViews */) {
            execProjectedViewsAction(view, action);  <---- this is executed
        }
    }
    break;
```

To learn more about change detection start with:

- [These 5 articles will make you an Angular Change Detection expert](https://blog.angularindepth.com/these-5-articles-will-make-you-an-angular-change-detection-expert-ed530d28930)

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts to explain the problem. Pretty complicated indeed (since comments are quite limited, see my answer)

Comment: @DieterRehbein, I've explored a bit more and this is expected behavior according to web components domain. I've updated my answer. Consider accepting it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@AngularInDepth.com

So there is no way to tell angular not to do this?  I'v e found the function markParentViewsForCheckProjectedViews in util.ts.

During debugging I changed the behaviour of the function to something like this:

```
export function markParentViewsForCheckProjectedViews(view: ViewData, endView: ViewData) {
  let currView: ViewData|null = view;
  while (currView && currView !== endView) {
    if (currView.state & ViewState.Attached) {
        currView.state |= ViewState.CheckProjectedViews;
    } else {
        currView.state &= ~ViewState.CheckProjectedViews;
    }
    currView = currView.viewContainerParent || currView.parent;
  }
}
```

This would solve my problem but of course I have no idea, if that introduces new problems. Maybe the `ChangeDetectorRef` could be extended by something like `detachProjectedViews()` (and a new ViewState `ProjectedViewsDetached`)?

Comment: cool, let's see how the issue goes. not sure that it's a good fix though, I'll need to investigate this. Interestingly, even without apparent projection like [in this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-check-projected-views), the interpolation is still triggered. Apparently, this is because as I explained in my answer it's because the template is bound to the hosting component. I'm not sure if it's a bug or design decision. I'll try to find out

Answer (score 0):

This is another problem related to *design* of content projection in angular.

Projected content effectively belongs to the component where it was defined. Everything, including DI, change detection, event handling, creating views from templates is done in the context of owner component, which in your case is `AppComponent`. Unfortunately there is no workaround for templates.

There are at least 2 other issues covering different sides the same problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14935, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842